How to navigate to a new page in Next.js with Link?
I am working on a Next.js project where I have a StudentsPage.tsx component that includes a button to navigate to a NewStudent.tsx page. However, instead of navigating to a new page, the NewStudent component is rendering directly on the StudentsPage.
How can I modify this so that clicking the "Add New" button navigates to the NewStudent.tsx page?
Here is my code:
StudentsPage.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import NewStudent from './NewStudent';

const StudentsPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white p-8 overflow-auto mt-16 h-screen">
      <h1>Students Page</h1>
      <Link href="/Admin/Students/NewStudent">
        <button className="bg-blue-400 text-white p-2">
          Add New
        </button>
      </Link>
      <NewStudent />
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudentsPage;
**NewStudent.tsx:**
import React from 'react';

const NewStudent = () => {
  return (
    <div>NewStudent page</div>
  );
};

export default NewStudent;

What I tried:

I tried using the Link component from Next.js to navigate from the StudentsPage to the NewStudent page. I also included the `<NewStudent />` component in `StudentsPage.tsx`, but it’s the same component that I want to open when the "Add New" button is clicked.

What I expected:

I expected that clicking the "Add New" button would take me to a new route `(/Admin/Students/NewStudent)` and display the `NewStudent.tsx` page separately.

What actually happened:

However, the `<NewStudent />` component is being rendered directly within the StudentsPage, instead of opening as a new page when the button is clicked. I'm looking for a way to make the button navigate to the new page, but it's not working as expected.


You need to read the docs to understand how the routing works in NextJS.
First your folder structure should be:
/pages
  └── /Admin
      └── /Students
          ├── StudentsPage.tsx
          └── NewStudent.tsx

where StudentsPage.tsx is:
// pages/Admin/Students/StudentsPage.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

const StudentsPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white p-8 overflow-auto mt-16 h-screen">
      <h1>Students Page</h1>
      <Link href="/Admin/Students/NewStudent">
        <button className="bg-blue-400 text-white p-2">
          Add New
        </button>
      </Link>
      {/* List of students would go here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudentsPage;

and NewStudent.tsx:
// pages/Admin/Students/NewStudent.tsx
import React from 'react';

const NewStudent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add New Student</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewStudent;

